# append multiple files and remove duplicates using dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, duplicates

So I have a few files that look like:

```
snpID  Gene
rs1  ABC1
rs2  ABC1
rs3  ABC25
rs4  PT4
rs5  MTND24
```

In different files there will be other snpIDs and Gene pairs but there may be duplicates for a given snpID but the corresponding "Gene" associated could be different . For eg:

```
snpID  Gene
rs100  URX1
rs95  KL4
rs1  ABC1
rs2  ABC1-MHT5
rs3  ABC25
rs4  PT4-FIL42
```

What I want to do is to append all the contents of the files and remove the duplicates if  they have the same snpID and Gene pair. Whereas if the corresponding Gene for a snpID is different it has to go into the same row
For the above example it should look like:

```
snpID  Gene
rs1  ABC1
rs2  ABC1, ABC1-MHT5
rs3  ABC25
rs4  PT4, PT4-FIL42
rs5  MTND2
rs100  URX1
rs95  KL4
```

I thought I could achieve this through creating dictionaries.

```
import glob
file_list = glob.glob('annotations.*')
dict_snps_genes = {}
for filename in file_list:
    with open(filename) as fileA:
        for line in fileA:
            col0 = line.split()[0]
            col1 = line.split()[1]
            dict_snps_genes[col0] = col1 

unique_dict_snps = {}
for key,value in dict_snps_genes:
    if key not in unique_dict_snps.keys():
        unique_dict_snps_genes[key] = value
```

I tested this before moving any further and this gives me an error like:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

PS: each file has around 8000 snpId-Gene pair and there are more than 5 files

Ideas on how to get past this!!

Comment: Instead of `col0 = line.split()[0]` and `col1 = line.split()[1]`, you can use only one function call: `col0, col1 = line.split()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looping over keys, but trying to assign those to both a key and value variable:

```
for key,value in dict_snps_genes:
```

change that to loop over `.items()`:

```
for key,value in dict_snps_genes.items():
```

or better still, if on Python 2.x, use `.iteritems():

```
for key,value in dict_snps_genes.iteritems():
```

Note that the way you read the files, you only ever store the last-read gene for any given snpID; you overwrite the previous one if you find another entry for that id.

Personally, I'd use `collections.defaultdict()` with a `set` default:

```
import glob
import collections

file_list = glob.glob('annotations.*')
snps_genes = collections.defaultdict(set)
for filename in file_list:
    with open(filename) as fileA:
        for line in fileA:
            snpid, gene = line.strip().split(None, 1)
            snps_genes[snpid].add(gene)
```

Now the values in `snps_genes` are sets of genes, each unique. Note that I split your line into 2 pieces on whitespace (`.split(None, 1)`) so that if there is any whitespace in the gene value, it'll be stored as such:

```
>>> 'id gene with whitespace'.split(None, 1)
['id', 'gene with whitespace']
```

By using `snpid, gene' as left-hand assignment expression Python takes the result of the split and assigns each piece to a separate variable; a handy trick here to save a line of code.

To output this to a new file, simply loop over the resulting `snps_genes` structure. Here is one that sorts everything:

```
for id in sorted(snps_genes):
    print id, ', '.join(sorted(snps_genes[id]))
```

Comment: As written, I don't think the second loop does anything, though.  Won't `unique_dict_snps` simply wind up being a copy of `dict_snps_genes`?

Comment: @DSM: I added a section on how I'd read the files instead. The way the files were being read, there would never *be* any dupes anyway.

Comment: Ummm... fundamentally the same answer except for my preference to use `inputfile` for cases like this

Comment: @JonClements: and I used `set` to start with. :-P

Comment: Oh well - you get +1 from me... just think my way of setting up the input is better :)

Comment: @JonClements: I agree, using `inputfile` is very nice for these kinds of cases, allowing you to simplify the code a bit further. I focused on the immediate problems of the OP, and that was how to deal with cleaning out duplicate genes for given ids. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not acquainted with the str.join method. When I use the above code, I only got the Gene names in the output file.

Comment: @jules: that's because my example loop never printed the `id` as well. :-) Added that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Great! But there's another problem it seems. First of all, if there is a duplicate snp-gene pair, the gene name is appearing twice and the duplicate is appearing on the next line. For e.g.: rs1 ABC1 is in the same line, and ABC1 also appears in a line below it.

Comment: @jules: Not entirely certain what you mean. Your input text has a `rs1 ABC1` line, and also `rs2 ABC1` and `rs2 ABC1-MHT5` lines. The code in my answer correctly handles these according to your sample output.

Comment: @jules: ah, I think I know what you mean; the newline wasn't being stripped. I added that in just earlier when I tested the code for you real quick. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters just edited the question to show the output that I get. Please check.

Comment: @jules: exactly, see the addition of the call to `.strip()` in my answer. (full line: `snpid, gene = line.strip().split(None, 1)`)

Answer (score 2):

I would write it as the following:

```
from glob import glob
import fileinput

infiles = glob('annotations.*')
lines = fileinput.input(infiles)
rows = (line.split() for line in lines)

from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
for row in rows:
    dd[row[0]].append(row[1])
```

If the values are to be unique, then:

```
dd = defaultdict(set)
for row in rows:
    dd[row[0]].add(row[1])
```

And then go from there....

Comment: @jules I typoed - should be `import fileinput` - sorry - edited (that's what you get for typing directly into SO!)

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the line after `col1 = line.split()[1]` with:

```
if col0 in dict_snps_genes:
    dict_snps_genes[col0].add(col1)
else:
    dict_snps_genes[col0] = set([col1])
```

You can read more about sets [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('annotations.*')
d = {}
for f in files:
    with open(f) as f:
        for line in f:
            col0, col1 = line.split()
            if col0 not in d:
                d[col0] = [col1]
            elif col1 not in d[col0]:
                d[col0].append(col1)
```

Will result into:

```
d = {
    "rs95": ['KL4'],
    "snpID": ['Gene'],
    "rs1": ['ABC1'],
    "rs2": ['ABC1', 'ABC1-MHT5'],
    "rs3": ['ABC25'],
    "rs4": ['PT4', 'PT4-FIL42'],
    "rs5": ['MTND24'],
    "rs100": ['URX1']
}
```

Comment: this does the job of removing the duplicates perfectly, but how do I uniqify the values in the dictionary for each key? I don't want the same gene name re-appearing.

Comment: Same as above, you could use sets. With the list you have in your hands, create a set with `set(listname)`.

Comment: Ups, didn't notice, fixed. Seems best solution to me, no `set`s or `defaultdict`s needed.